# Bootstrap 4: Fixed Top Navbar with container properties

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, nav, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

So by default when you create a Bootstrap 4 Navbar, it will have the properties of a `container-fluid` instead of `container`, so how does one get it to have the properties of container

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```

I've seen several similar Questions but I hope my solution helps you out:

Answer (score 0):

The simplest Answer to this question is to add `container` in you nav class. Below is an example:

```
<nav class="navbar container fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```